# Upgrading from Spark 1.6 to 2.1 - Incompatible Class Change Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I'm upgrading from Spark 1.6 to 2.1 version (HortonWorks Distribution). Below explaining **Stage 1** and Stage 2 scenario, Stage 1 with successful execution and **Stage 2** failing.

**Stage 1**

POM xml dependencies for Spark 1.6.3 (which is working absolutely fine) are,

```
scala tools version 2.10
scala version 2.10.5
scala compiler version 2.10.6
spark-core_2.10
spark-sql_2.10
spark version 1.6.3
```

There is common set of libraries used which are -

```
commons-csv-1.4.jar
commons-configuration2-2.1.1.jar
commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
commons-email-1.4.jar
javax.mail-1.5.2.jar
sqoop-1.4.6.2.3.0.12-7.jar
avro-mapred-1.8.2.jar
avro-1.8.2.jar
guava-14.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.4.4.jar
jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar
jackson-core-2.4.4.jar
xdb6.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar
```

**Stage 2**

As I change the dependencies and spark version in POM.xml to -

```
scala tools version 2.11
scala version 2.11.8
scala compiler version 2.11.8
spark-core_2.11
spark-sql_2.11
spark version 2.1.0
```

Also, the from the common set of libraries, I'm just changing -

```
jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.6.5.jar
jackson-core-2.6.5.jar
jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar
```

While, I take a build and try to run it on the cluster with Spark configuration as 2.1 and scala as 2.11.8, it is failing with below error.

```
INFO: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: 
class com.xxx.xxx.xxx.DQListener has interface 
org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener as super class
```

I'm sure that the issue is with importing correct jars but not able to find out which one. I would appreciate if anybody could help to resolve this please.

Comment: If by chance you're running in a custom hadoop/spark distro (like Cloudera or Hortonworks), maybe the discussion in this link could help you. https://github.com/qubole/sparklens/issues/1

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks ! I'm running it on Hortonworks distribution.

Comment: Try using spark version `2.1.0.${hdp.version}`, the hdp version must contain the **build number**, you can check all avaliable versions in the [horton public maven _repo_](http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/), also you need to [**configure** maven](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/74655/where-can-i-find-hdp-maven-repos.html) to use that repo.